# Generating choropleth map for each geographical unit in a shapefile

Tags: for-loop, matplotlib, classification, geopandas, shapefile

I have a shapefile (defined as data) with a column named "pln_area" that defines the geographical units (something like census tract in the U.S. or Canada). I am trying to generate choropleth maps based on another column named "LSTR" (using FisherJenks classification algorithm) for each of my geographical units, which are 55 in total. However, my code only produces maps for the first two (in alphabetic order) and I cannot figure out why!

You can find the shapefile I am trying to run the code on from the following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XtxY0T0s7d3Af3XDQ1mRI5KYacEvULwr?usp=sharing

```
use = data.pln_area.unique()
for pln_area in use:
    cgdf = data[data.pln_area==pln_area]
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12, 8))
    cgdf.plot(column="LSTR", k=5, scheme="FisherJenks", ax=ax,
              edgecolor='grey', legend=True, cmap="Blues", alpha=0.6)
    plt.title(f'{pln_area}')
    ax.set_axis_off()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! first - why not just `data.plot("LST")`? I'm assuming `data` is a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame`? And beyond that - please check out the guide to [ask]. We really can't help without knowing what your types are, the shapes of the data, etc. Ideally, please provide a full [mre]. But at the very least, post the result of `print(data)` and other objects as formatted code blocks (no images please!) into your question so we know what we're working with. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thank you, Michael, for the useful info on how to ask a question here. I have edited my question to provide a link to my data. I hope this helps. I am using for-loop since I intend to produce a plot for each of the unique values in my "pln_area" column, which are 55 in total. I certainly want to avoid repeating the same procedure 55 times.

Comment: ok. sorry but it's tough to debug this with the info we have. can you put a print statement and make sure the loop is being called 55 times with different values of pln_area, and that cgdf has non-zero length in each loop? also, are you running this from a terminal or something like jupyterlab? if you save the figure to a different file in each loop, does that help?